# Regular Expression Pattern - Query

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to find create a pattern that would satisfy below rules

```
mydomain.com
www.mydomain.com
www.alternatedomain.com
www100.mydomain.com
online.mydomain.com
subl.mydomain.com
```

The pattern that i have created so far doesnt work.

I may or may not have values before mydomain.

```
private static final String MY_PATTERN =
 "((www*|online|subl)*\\.((mydomain|alternatedomain)\\.(com)$))";
```

And if it has values it should belong to a restrictive set

Comment: Check https://regex101.com/r/d0Ya7B/1

Comment: Thank you !! I should have replied earlier. Though this works i have a query on the initial part of the regex why do we need ?: in the first part of the check. The regex seems to be returning results even without that ?:.

Comment: Why do you capture the parts of the string? Are you using them later? If not, use *non-capturing groups*, `(?:...)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest  using

```
String rx = "^(?:(?:www\\d*|online|subl)*\\.)?(?:mydomain|alternatedomain)\\.com$";
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1ugTCQ/1)

I removed or converted to [non-capturing groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-what-does-do) all capturing groups in the pattern. If you are using those parts of the string later, revert them.

If you use the regex with `.matches()` method remove `^` and `$`, they are redundant then, as the method makes sure the entire string matches the pattern.

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:(?:www\\d*|online|subl)*\\.)?` - an optional non-capturing group matching

  - `(?:www\\d*|online|subl)*` - `www` and 0+ digits, or `online` or `subl`
  - `\\.` - a dot
- `(?:mydomain|alternatedomain)` - a non-capturing group matching either `mydomain` or `alternatedomain`
- `\\.com` - `.com` substring
- `$` - end of string.

Answer (score 1):

Try `((www\\d*|online|subl)\\.)?(mydomain|alternatedomain)\\.com`

You can test your regex online [here](https://regex101.com/) but don't forget to replace the `\\` with a single `\` (because in Java code `\\` means a `\` in regex)